# How to create UITableViewController in Xcode 6 using New>File... template "wizard"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I would like to know how to create UITableViewController in Xcode 6 using the New>File... template "wizard".

I have tried to create one by selecting

**"New File>iOS>Source>Objective C File>"**

Then I click **next**, then give the **file name** and select **File type** catagory and finally select **UITableViewController** from the drop down list.

However when this is done I end up with a file with no UITableView delegate classes or anything in it?

Im sure back in old XCode versions UITableViewController could be selected and it would create a file with the delegates methods all set up for you?

Comment: If you really did what you say you did, then something must be wrong with your Xcode, because it works fine for me. What version of Xcode are you using (mine is 6.1.1)?

Comment: Also running 6.1.1 When I create it I name it location, but this is what the implementation looks like **@implementation UITableViewController (location)** instead i think it should look like **@implementation locationUITableViewController ()** other than that I have no methods in the ViewController I just created.

Comment: It should just be "@implementation location" if that's what you called your class (no parentheses after the name).

Comment: Yea I know, I have changed my classes to what they should be after looking at a few older examples of stuff I have done in the past.. But I dont know why XCode is doing this... Think I need to fix it as its a pain in the butt.

Comment: You are creating a category rather than a subclass.  You should be using the **Cocoa Class** option within **iOS>Source**, NOT **Objective C File**.

Comment: @pbasdf Yes that worked better (set up implementation correctly) however still did now add any of the UITableViewController method delegates... weird. I mean I know most of them myself and can add them easily but would think xcode would do this for me.... like it used to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to use the "New File Wizard" then after you select >File>New>File...

Choose *Cocoa Touch Class*

[image: Choose a template for your new file]

After clicking "Next" name your new class, and make it a subclass of `UITableViewController`.

[image]

Remember you can always go back to first principals with blank header and implementation files and type the appropriate code in to create a subclass of UITableViewController.

For example in your blank header file...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface New_TableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```